# How to identify if a row is visible in a listview

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a situation involving animation of listview's item appearances.

I have a few views in a ScollView , the last of which is the listview. I have attached an appearence animation of the row (a fade in animation). 
The problem I have is that when the screen is loaded , the getView() of listview already executes for the initial items , even though the listview is not currently in view.

Hence when a user scroll downs , he sees the list plainly.

I am unsure how to go about this situation . Is there any callback that can be invoked when a row from a listview becomes visible on screen ? .

Comment: I think I can help with this, but first do you understand about list view recycling views? In any case we need to see the code you are trying. If you tag me in a comment once you add it I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a callback (`OnScrollChangeListener`), first visible index and last visible index etc. You can achieve what you are trying to using combination of these.

But you need to try that yourself first. No one can simply write a code for you.

You can learn about listview [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Comment: Let me look into this .